# Angular 2 Aot : Zoneware (SystemJS) XHR error

Tags: javascript, angular, angular2-aot

I am  working on Angular Ahead of Time Compilation(AoT), where I have generated build.js file and while loading, stuck with below issue

```
(SystemJS) XHR error (404 Not Found) loading http://localhost:58082/aot/app/app.module.ngfactory
```

Included below files in index.html

```
<script src="shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="zone.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three possibilities of getting this issue

1) we include this script in index.html page

```
 <script>window.module = 'aot';</script>
```

So We have to include in every component the module field along with selector and template

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'myapp',
    templateUrl: '../../master/html/test.html'
})
```

2)This script should be at the bottom of html page

```
<script src="dist/build.js"></script>
```

3)Last but important , No lazy loading for Ahead of time compilation

This resolved my issues and app with AOT is running but inside stuck with few issues like Zoneware error of stack undefined.Resolving them.